# Launch screen doesn't show first after the first launch time?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing App with `React native`.
I set an image in the `launchScreen.Xib`.
The first time, the launch screen works well. After the launch screen hide,
then I will see the View **MainView**.
I shut up the App in the background. A moment later, I tap the App icon to launch the App again.
To my surprise, the App will show the **MainView** first, the MainView continue show 0.2 seconds.

After the **MainView** flash, the launch screen show now. A few seconds later, the **MainView** show again.
My issue is the **MainView** will show before the launch screen in the later launch time.

In my opinion, the launch screen should show first and the **MainView** show later.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"patient"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

## This is my code above in the `AppDelegate.m`. This is the initial code of `React native`.

One more thing, the **MainView** show a moment, and the screen shows a white view instead of the **MainView**, a moment later, the **MainView** show again.

Comment: Please explain "I shut up the App in the background."   Do you mean you killed the app, or merely switched it to the background?  Also, is this happening on an actual device or just in simulator?

Comment: @Smartcat I killed the app. This happened on an actual device iPhone6.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you’re trying to instantiate and show with timer your own launch screen (not good!) while also asking iOS to do one.  Just get rid of most or all of this code.  Use the standard approach of having a launch storyboard then set up your main VC as normal in your appDelegate.

Using that timer is making assumptions about the timing of each app launch that iOS can’t guarantee.

Comment: I used to the launch storyboard and I don't write the timer in the `Appdelegate.m`, I face this question too.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: At first, I only set the `Launch Storyboard`, the question is shown.

Comment: Ok then the question needs to be rewitten to explain what code you were doing to cause what effect, and then if you changed the code, what then is the effect, and then to be clear on your question to us.  If you originally had a launch storyboard, and it showed the launch screen and a moment later then showed the main view, but after that you killed the app and relaunched it, and it went straight to the app view, skipping the launch screen, so what?  iOS probably just cached your app.  There's no guarantee of launch screen. It's there just to seem like the launch is fast *if* it takes a while.

Comment: I did some research, given that I know nothing about React native, and found the following articles that may help you.  I don't see anything about doing your own timer, however.  [Article1](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae).  [Article2](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/change-default-launch-screen-in-react-native-ios-app-544f94f1e947)

Comment: Thank you very much. Due to My network is wrong, I can't open the "medium.com". Maybe I can open the "medium.com" a few months later.